# Vue linter - Types of property '$emit' are incompatible

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint, vue-test-utils, vitest

In the unit tests of a Vue3 application (Typescript + Composition API), using `vitest` and `@vue/test-utils`, my linter displays an error when I assign the result of `shallowMount` function to a variable typed `VueWrapper`.

```
const wrapper: VueWrapper = shallowMount(ResultsHistory, {
  // mount options...
});
```

The error is the following:

```
[...]
  Types of property '$emit' are incompatible.
    Type '((event: "myEvent", arg0: number) => void) & ((event: "anotherEvent", arg0: number) => void)' is not assignable to type '(event: string, ...args: any[]) => void'.
      Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"myEvent"'.ts(2322)
```

The events are typed following the [official documentation](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/composition-api.html#typing-component-emits), using type declaration:

```
const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: 'myEvent', id: number): void
  (e: 'anotherEvent', value: string): void
}>()
```

My dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.2.41",
    "vue-i18n": "^9.2.2",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n": "^6.0.3",
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.2.0",
    "@types/jsdom": "^16.2.15",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.3",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^3.2.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^7.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^11.0.2",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.2.1",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.1.3",
    "eslint": "^8.27.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.7.0",
    "jsdom": "^19.0.0",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "sass": "^1.56.0",
    "typescript": "~4.6.3",
    "vite": "^3.2.3",
    "vitest": "^0.24.5",
    "vue-tsc": "^1.0.9"
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, I've faced the same problem right now; I'm going to tell you what's the solution for that as soon as I find it :D

#edit:
How did you actually declared `defineEmits()` in your component? :)

Comment: @Alan, I updated the question to answer your question

Comment: Can you try to remove the type declaration from this line `const wrapper: VueWrapper = shallowMount(ResultsHistory, {`? If this is your real line of code, then you don't need this type declaration here, because TypeScript will know this by inference :) 
`const wrapper = shallowMount(ResultsHistory, {` should do the job.

Comment: Removing the typing removes the linter error for this line. But many other linter errors appear when I try to use the wrapper, like when I do `wrapper.vm` for example. Without explicit typing, it's considered as `any`.

Answer (score 1):

@Eria, in my case, the problem was that I declared (just like you did)
`const wrapper: VueWrapper` looks like the `VueWrapper` type is too general, and TypeScript doesn't accept that in this case.

So, what I did, is wrote a simple function that mounts your component (just like you do later on) like:

```
const mountComponent = () => shallowMount(ResultsHistory, {
  // mount options...
});
```

And then, in the line, you declare your wrapper, you do it like so:

```
const wrapper: ReturnType<typeof mountComponent> = shallowMount(ResultHistory, { ...
```

Another story is that - in most cases - you shouldn't access `the wrapper. I'm in your tests. I highly recommend [this talk from the Vue Toronto conf by Natalia Tepluhina](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L_BK8zXGdBM); it's just 25 minutes, but it's worth it, and you'll surely learn some good practices :)

Comment: Thx for the tip. I'll give it a try. But, about your last comment: how would you test a Vue component without accessing the `wrapper`? It's basically the entry point for everything in test-utils.

Comment: It's not about not accessing the `wrapper` but about not accessing the `wrapper.vm`; you should access the elements themself, as shown in the video. ;) So, for example, instead of invoking `wrapper.vm.someClickHandler()` you should click on the button itself, as the user does; etc. :)

Comment: Yes, I know that. Thx